# Generate list of random names - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of names, with each one being different.  Here is my code right now, but all it does it create multiple instances of the same name.

```
import random

first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

full_name=random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)

group=full_name*3
```

For example, this would show up as:

```
John Smith
John Smith
John Smith
```

But I want something like:

```
John Williams
Andy Johnson
Joe Johnson
```

Answer (score 6):

you're just duplicating your string here. Random occurs only once.

Do it in a generator comprehension instead, and join the results with space:

```
import random

first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

group=" ".join(random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names) for _ in range(3))


print(group)
```

outputs:

```
Joe Williams Joe Johnson Joe Smith
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you generated one name and then replicated it three times.

If you want three different names, then loop through your choice routine three times:

```
group = []
for i in range(3):
    full_name=random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
    group.append(full_name)
 #assuming he wants at least some kind of seperator between the names.
 group_string = ", ".join(group)
```

BTW, do you really want **group** to be all the names just concatenated?

Answer (score 2):

Why you complicate such a simple task :)

Maybe this will help: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(fake.name())
```

Faker has a lot of usefull providers you can use: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the output is on one line with spaces separating each name, you can simplify the code and store every name in one list, albeit you append names in the "first name" "last name" pattern. From there you can print 6 names at the end all seperated by a space, giving you three full names. In all, the 'random.choice()' function will need to be called 6 times.

```
import random

first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')
names = []
for i in range(3):
    names.append(random.choice(first_name)
    names.append(random.choice(last_name)

print ' '.join(names)
```

output

```
Andy Smith Andy Williams John Johnson
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is use `*3` on a string which means it will copy that string three times.

To do what you want, you have to call `random.choice` for first name and for last name three times.

```
full_name1 = random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
full_name2 = random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
full_name3 = random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)

group = full_name1 + " " + full_name2 + " " + full_name3
```

You can also do that in a `for` loop to not duplicate the code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke `random.choice()` 3 times other than invoking once and print the same fullname 3 times

```
import random

first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')
group = list()
for x in range(3):
    fullname = random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
    group.add(fullname)
print " ".join(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

... just shorter.

```
from random import choice
first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

name = " ".join(["%s %s" % (choice(first_names), choice(last_names)) for _ in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the main part in a function with a print in it and then call the function 3 times.

```
def name():
    import random
    
    first_names=('John','Andy','Joe')
    last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')
    
    full_name=random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
    print(full_name)
for _ in range(3):
    name()
```

Answer (score 0):

> pip install names

Create random names with python
Then to create random names just do:

```
import names

for i in range(10):
    print(names.get_full_name())
```